# Minimum distance of a point from four other points

Tags: analytic-geometry, problem-solving

In this question in my textbook:

> Let $A(0,1), B(1,1), C(1,-1), D(-1,0)$ be four points. If P be any other point, then $PA+PB+PC+PD=d$, where $[d] =$

What I have done: Taken two triangles $PAB$ and $PAD$, we know that the sum of two sides is greater than the other, thus $PA+PB≥AB$ and $PC+PD≥CD$, adding we get: $PA+PB+PC+PD≥AB+CD$. This approach gives $3$, and if we take the triangles $PAC$ and $PCD$, we get $4$, which is the correct one. Why this discrepancy?

Comment: You left out the actual question from the part you quoted.

Comment: I don't think I did. The question asks us to find the value of $d$ and put it in the greatest integer function. There appears to be a grammatical mistake in the question, which I've now corrected.

Comment: The value of $d$ depends on the point $P$. It is not the same if $P=(0,0)$ vs. $P=(100,100)$ for example. If there is a question about $d$ then that's missing from what  you quoted.